# Biogeme fails to install and run on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: software-installation, compiling, python3, statistical

I wanted to ask about the installation of one of most important open source freeware for discrete choice modeling data estimation: Biogeme.

I am trying to install it on my machine (Thinkpad x201, 8gb, Intel i5 dual 2.7GHz) running Ubuntu 16.04.

After installing it from the .deb file provided at http://biogeme.epfl.ch/home.html , I run it from a terminal and I get the following:

```
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
biogeme 2.4 [Mon Nov 2 00:56:45 CET 2015]
Michel Bierlaire, EPFL
-- Compiled by bierlair on Linux
See http://biogeme.epfl.ch
                    !! CFSQP is available !!
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    "In every non-trivial program there is at least one bug."


[12:58:57]patBiogeme.cc:134  Read default.par
Warning:  Error: File sample.dat is missing

Warning:  Error: File sample.dat is missing

Warning:  Error: File sample.dat is missing
```

while if I try to compile it as explained here: http://biogeme.epfl.ch/install.html

I get the following error while running the `make` command:

```
libtool:   error: 'patLegendre.lo' is not a valid libtool object
Makefile:778: set of instructions for "libbisonbiogeme.la" failed

make[2]: *** [libbisonbiogeme.la] Errore 1
Makefile:441: set of instructions for "install-recursive" failed
make: *** [install-recursive] Errore 1
```

I don't know if anybody can help, any support would be appreciated!

Thank you very much

Comment: In the first instance, try locating + changing to the directory that contains the `sample.dat` file before running the program. If you still want help compiling from source after that, then you will need to post the actual error message.

Comment: I wasn't able to locate it.. Since running  `biogeme` in the terminal generates the `default.par` file every time, maybe it is supposed to do the same with the `sample.dat`? You're right about the error message for compiling, I'll post it thanks.

Comment: Possibly related to https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/biogeme/conversations/topics/1871?l=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install the `biogeme` program, download the deb file at http://biogeme.epfl.ch/distrib/biogeme_2.4.0-1_amd64.deb and run `sudo dpkg -i biogeme_2.4.0-1_amd64.deb`. This will install the necessary binaries to your `/usr/local/bin` directory.

As can be seen in section 4 of page 6 of the PDF at http://biogeme.epfl.ch/documentation/bisonfirstmodel-2.4.pdf, to use the program, you need to provide `biogeme` with two arguments: a model and a `.dat` file. Following section 4 of page 6 of the aforementioned PDF, we will use the logit model and the data file for the Swissmetro example, which can be found at http://biogeme.epfl.ch/examples_swissmetro.html. First, download the `01logit` model file at http://biogeme.epfl.ch/bison/01logit.mod. Second, download the `swissmetro.dat` data file at http://biogeme.epfl.ch/swissmetro.dat. Third, run `biogeme 01logit swissmetro.dat`. Notice that the program will tell you that `01logit.par` does not exist and it will try to use `default.par` instead (and if `default.par` is missing, it will create it and then use it). This behavior is expected as stated in the second bullet point of page 7 of the aforementioned PDF.

Comment: Thank you very much. This was really useful and also made me understand how the software actually works. Clarified many things. Thank you once

Comment: @AndreaCiccorelli No problem at all!